# Plot 2 xts object with 2 y-axis different scales

Tags: r, ggplot2, xts

I am having problems while plotting 2 different variables in the same chart. I want to plot the COT Balance and the Price variables of USD/BRL(*data is an xts object*).

```
tail(COT_USD_BRL)
           Long.Positions Short.Positions Change.Long Change.Short X..Long X..Short
2019-11-12           1662           11742        -564         -956     3.1     21.9
2019-11-19           2619           10955         957         -788     4.6     19.2
2019-11-26           3935            9697        1316        -1258     5.7     14.0
2019-12-03           7351           11066        3416         1369    11.9     17.9
2019-12-10           8339            7046         988        -4020    14.3     12.1
2019-12-17           4681           10964       -3658         3918     8.6     20.2
           COT.Balance  Price
2019-11-12       -18.8 4.1677
2019-11-19       -14.6 4.1945
2019-11-26        -8.3 4.2332
2019-12-03        -6.0 4.2066
2019-12-10         2.2 4.1470
2019-12-17       -11.6 4.0719
```

The scales are different. The price variable is not fitting right the second scale and I don't know why. Someone could help me?
The code I'm using is:

```
  ggplot(data = COT_USD_BRL, aes(x = index(COT_USD_BRL), y = COT_USD_BRL$COT.Balance)) +
  geom_line(inherit.aes = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "USD_BRL", sec.axis = sec_axis(~. /(100)+3.2)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = index(COT_USD_BRL), y = COT_USD_BRL$Price), color = "red") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 months", date_labels = "%b-%Y") + theme_linedraw()
```

This is the plot:

[COT Balance x Price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYnTG.jpg)

Please, let me know if I miss some usefull information.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `sec.axis` only create an axis labeling but it is not use as  a referential axis to plot data. So your second set of data is plotting based on the left y-axis. You need to apply a scale factor to your second y value `Price` in order to match to the left y-axis and values of `USD_BRL`.

Without a reproducible example of your dataset (see here: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)), it is hard to be sure of the correct scale factor, but maybe you should start with this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = COT_USD_BRL, aes(x = index(COT_USD_BRL), y = COT_USD_BRL$COT.Balance)) +
  geom_line(inherit.aes = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "USD_BRL", sec.axis = sec_axis(~. /10, name = "Price") +
  geom_line(aes(x = index(COT_USD_BRL), y = COT_USD_BRL$Price*10), color = "red") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 months", date_labels = "%b-%Y") + theme_linedraw()
```

Hope it helps you to figure out the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, man. You solved my problem. Now I understood how to rescale the plot, it will help me a lot.

Comment: Glad that I was able to help you ;)